# Issues with while loop using turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Turtle must draw two overlapping rectangles. Then, move outside of the boundaries of both rectangles. The turtle must start drawing/moving in random directions until it's on the boundary of or inside rectangle one, but NOT rectangle two. It should also count and print the number of steps taken before reaching it.

I can't seem to get the while statement working. The issue is in the function ranWalkRects(t,x0,y0,x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2,dz)

```
def ranWalkRects(t,x0,y0,x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2,dz):
    """has turtle t start at x0,y0 outside of both rectangles.
    Execute a random walk until it is inside or on the boundary of rectangle 1 but not
    inside or on the boundary of rectangle 2. Assume that rectangle 1 overlaps rectangle
    2 but that rectangle 1 does not lie entirely inside rectangle 2. Print out how many
    times the turtle moves from its starting position to the final position. Dz is
    the step size for the random walk. """

    rec1 = isInRect(t,x1,y1,w1,h1)
    rec2 = isInRect(t,x2,y2,w2,h2)
    t.pu()
    t.goto(x0,y0)
    t.pd()
    num_steps = 0
    while (rec1 and rec2) and (not rec1 and not rec2) and not (rec1 and not rec2):
        ngl = random.randint(0,359)
        t.lt(ngl)
        t.fd(dz)
        num_steps+=1
        x0,y0 = t.pos()
    print("Turtle takes ", num_steps,"steps before entering the rectangle")

ranWalkRects(tess,100,100,50,50,100,75,30,30,100,75,20)
```

It won't take any steps after leaving the boundaries of the two rectangles and I'm not sure why.

Comment: how should all of `(rec1 and rec2) and (not rec1 and not rec2) and not (rec1 and not rec2)` being True ?

Comment: then just use : while not (rect1 and not rect 2)

Comment: Then make the starting point is ```True``` with while not(rect1 and not rect2)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post

Comment: tags got changed?? How is none of the answers helping you? This is getting absurd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picture a simpler approach than you're using:

```
def ranWalkRects(t, x0, y0, x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2, dz):
    t.pu()
    t.goto(x0, y0)
    t.pd()
    num_steps = 0

    in_rec1 = isInRect(t, x1, y1, w1, h1)
    in_rec2 = isInRect(t, x2, y2, w2, h2)

    while not in_rec1 or in_rec2:
        angle = random.randrange(360)
        t.lt(angle)
        t.fd(dz)
        num_steps += 1

        in_rec1 = isInRect(t, x1, y1, w1, h1)
        in_rec2 = isInRect(t, x2, y2, w2, h2)

    print("Turtle takes", num_steps, "steps before entering the rectangle.")
```

But my belief is that `isInRect()` is also suspect as the first thing it does is *move the turtle* without saving its current position!  How can you tell if the turtle is in the rectangle once you move it elsewhere?  This probably should be a mathematical determination and not require actually moving the turtle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your logic for the rectangle cases, but given that rec1 and rec2 are True False for conditions in rectangle 1 and 2. your explanation would be:

while( not rec2) is already enough since it must run while in any case except where rec2 is True. Look at your logic sets possible (rec1,rec2)

(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1) -> (run),(dont run),(run),(dont run)
so we want (0,0) or (1,0) -> (X,0) -> not rec2

And you want it to run in all cases except where it is in rec2. simplifying the logic leaves (not rec2). Have a look at boolean equations. *this kinda means rec1 is not needed

Also note that your functions that update rec1 and rec2 are not in the while loop. You probably want these inside as well otherwise they will never be updated during the while loop and so if you do enter it you will never know where you are. Also, do debug by printing the values of x0,y0 in the loop and double check your logic. Here is a altered function for you to try.

```
def ranWalkRects(t,x0,y0,x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2,dz):
    """has turtle t start at x0,y0 outside of both rectangles.
    Execute a random walk until it is inside or on the boundary of rectangle 1 but not
    inside or on the boundary of rectangle 2. Assume that rectangle 1 overlaps rectangle
    2 but that rectangle 1 does not lie entirely inside rectangle 2. Print out how many
    times the turtle moves from its starting position to the final position. Dz is
    the step size for the random walk. """

    rec1 = isInRect(t,x1,y1,w1,h1)
    rec2 = isInRect(t,x2,y2,w2,h2)
    t.pu()
    t.goto(x0,y0)
    t.pd()
    num_steps = 0
    while not rec2:
        ngl = random.randint(0,359)
        t.lt(ngl)
        t.fd(dz)
        num_steps+=1
        x0,y0 = t.pos()
        print(x0,y0) # print for debug. 
        rec1 = isInRect(t,x1,y1,w1,h1) #this updates your conditions
        rec2 = isInRect(t,x2,y2,w2,h2)
    print("Turtle takes ", num_steps,"steps before entering the rectangle")

ranWalkRects(tess,100,100,50,50,100,75,30,30,100,75,20)
```

Of course this is assuming that your logic is correct, and the tests are working properly. I recommend you debug and try substituting dummy values for x0 and y0 to check that your logic and tests are working.

Also do check that you did initialized the rectangles at least graphically. you never called rectangle in the script uploaded.